# @change method is taking the previeous selected value of select box

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a country Id which is bind by v-model. Whenever I change the select box i call an event @change which calls a method *country_change* that will fetch the value of the states belongin to that perticular country id.
The porblem is that the states which I am fetching belongs to the prevously selected country id, not the country id which is currently selected.
Seems like as if the @change method is running before the v-model bind value of country id is being changed.

```
     <select class="custom-select form-control" id="country" name="country" v-model="country" @click="country_change">
        <option value="">Select Country</option>
        @foreach($countries as $country)
        {
          <option value="{{ $country->id }}" >{{ $country->name }}</option>
        }
        @endforeach
      </select>
```

```
  data: function () {
    return {
      country: '101',
      states: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    country_change: function () {
      axios
      .get('/states/'+this.country)
      .then(res => this.states = res.data )
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
  }
```

Comment: try with `@input` instread of `@change`

Comment: @input doesn't solved my problem

Comment: i have used `@change @input @click` all giving same results

Comment: First Select    --    `country:"75"
states:Array[9]
0:Object
country_id:79
created_at:null
id:1325
name:"Estuaire"
updated_at:null
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
country_id:79
created_at:null
id:1328
name:"Ngounie"
updated_at:null
4:Object
5:Object
6:Object
7:Object
8:Object
`

Comment: Second Select --   `country:"74"
states:Array[5]
0:Object
country_id:77
created_at:null
id:1317
name:"Iles du Vent"
updated_at:null
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
country_id:77
created_at:null
id:1320
name:"Tuamotu"
updated_at:null
4:Object

`

Comment: See the country_id is not same as country, its take one or two  steps previously selected countries id

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem was with the vue.js devtool. It was showing the results corresponding to the previously select value of select-box.